# How can I open file location to show a file?

Tags: android, file, file-location

I am making video player app. And I want to add option like, when user taps,it opens default file manager to show this video file's location.

> Here is sample from Windows OS
>   [image]

Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by this method.

```
public void open_Folder(String location)
{
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
     + File.separator+ location + File.separator);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "set your data type");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select file manager app."));
}
```